# Navigate from NavigationController to another NavigationController with a back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

[image]

Hello,
so i have this `storyboard` structure i have a `button` in `ViewController B` i need that `button` to point to the bottom `NavigationController` in which it has the `ViewController C` as `rootViewController` so when i press a `button` in `ViewContoller B` it takes me to `C` now i need a back button on `C` to take me back to `B`

i have tried looking but all of the reference materials show how to navigate between `ViewController` not `NavigationControllers`

Comment: Why do you use a second navigation controller?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR i have a LocationPicker ViewController that needs to be opened from a rootViewController of a NavigationController

Comment: @Jhon you can try my answer it will work for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot push Navigation Controller inside another uinavigation controller but alternativaly you can present another nav controller.
Hope it works for you.
I have created simple demo like this.
[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCustom: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func btnForward(_ sender: Any) {
        /*Uncomment the code if you want to present programatically*/
        /*if let navi2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav2"){
            self.present(navi2, animated: true) {
            }
        }*/
    }

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCustom: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: Any) {
        if let parentNav = self.navigationController {
            parentNav.dismiss(animated: true) {

            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: what is the "nav2" here is it the storyboard id for the second navigation controller?

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot. ca you also tell me how i can display the default back button on ViewController C

Comment: you can put barbutton item in navigationbar but you have to connect btnBack method with it

Comment: can u share a code snippet please on how to do that  i am kind of new to swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198515/discussion-between-jhon-and-jaydeep-vyas).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **single navigation controller**, but overwrite the back buttons action.

By default it will pop the current view controller from the navigation stack and go to the previous one.

On the **back action in VC B just push to the VC C**, you can do this either in storyBoard by drag-drop from the back button to VC C or by code by writing:

```
self.navigationControlller.push(VC C)
```

Comment: i cant use a single NavigationController i have a LocationPicker ViewController that needs to be opened from a rootViewController of a NavigationController

Answer (score 0):

If using 2 `navigationControllers` is a requirement that cannot be avoided, you can solve the problem statement in the following way.

In `ViewControllerC` on a `UIButton's` tap event, get the instance of `ViewControllerB` in the parent `navigationController` and pop to it like so,

```
@objc func backAction() {
    let parentNav = self.navigationController?.navigationController
    if let vcB = parentNav?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is ViewControllerB }) {
        parentNav?.popToViewController(vcB, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Add the `backAction()` to `backButton's` target like,

```
backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: ok i tried it and create a back button using this code `let backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_icon.png"), for: .normal)
        backButton.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
        backButton.setTitleColor(backButton.tintColor, for: .normal)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: "backAction", for: .touchUpInside)

       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton` and added your code on the tap event it gives an error like 'NSInvalidArgumentException' unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: The issue is because the signature of the method and its selector doesn't match. I've updated the code.

Comment: i tried it but nothing happens after i click the back button

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside your C's viewController back button action method. Also you have to give identifiers names to your views in the storyboard screen.

```
...

//It possible to change between different storyboards, but in your case all the views share the same storyboard.

UIStoryboard* storyboardOfA_B = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"storyboardOfA_B" bundle:nil]; 
UINavigationController* navigationControllerOfA_B = [storyboardOfA_B instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationControllerOfA_B"];
UIViewController* viewControllerB = [storyboardOfA_B instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerB"];

//I'm supposing that you have the action method of the back button in the C's view controller so I use self.
UINavigationController* navigationControllerOfC = self.navigationController;

[navigationControllerOfC pushViewController: navigationControllerOfA_B animated:NO];    
[navigationControllerOfA_B pushViewController: viewControllerB animated:NO];

...
```

Maybe this is not the best way but is a way